# NDSolve value precision

Tags: differential-equations

I have a function of a numerical integral that works perfectly. Because I found out that I can get the same result using NDSolve in a much faster way (around 0.15s using the integral and 0.02s using NDSolve, per point), I translated this integral (and, in the future, other problematic integrals) into an ODE. The thing is that from some values it returns a lot of errors.

The integral is

```
FAu[q_?NumericQ] := 1/92.57237188637842`20 NIntegrate[
If[q == 0 \[Or] r == 0, r^2/(1 + E^((r - 6.38`20)/0.535`20)), 
Sin[q r ]/q  r/(1 + E^((r - 6.38`20)/0.535`20))], {r, 0, 100}, 
MinRecursion -> 3, MaxRecursion -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 15, 
PrecisionGoal -> 7, AccuracyGoal -> \[Infinity]];
```

and the corresponding NDSolve version is

```
FAu1[q_] := If[q == 0, 1, NDSolveValue[{y'[r] == 
1/92.57237188637842 Sin[q r]/q r/(1 + E^((r - 6.38)/0.535)), 
y[0] == 0}, y[100], {r, 0, 100}]]
```

Here is a plot to compare the functions:

```
T = ParallelTable[{q, Abs@FAu[q/0.197]}, {q, 0, 2, 1/1000}];
A = ListLogPlot[T, PlotStyle -> Red]
B = LogPlot[Abs@FAu1[q/0.197], {q, 0, 2}]
Show[A, B]
```

[image]
The ODE versions is so much faster that Plot is able to create the graph in a small amount of time, while the numerical integral version need to be plotted as a list. The blue line corresponds to the ODE, and, as you can see, for values q>1 it starts giving a lot of errors. I would like to find out why and how to solve this problem. The things I tried to do is to add WorkingPrecision->20 (and adding SetPrecision[...,20] around the equations) all that does is pushing the errors a little bit farther. I also tried adding AccuracyGoal->Infinity & PrecisionGoal->15 at the same time but for some reason I get a 'ComplexInfinity' error. Ideally, I would like to be able to get a good precision for values of q at least in [0,2000].

Just to be clear, I do not wish to rewrite the integral version in a more efficient way, I want to focus on the ODE.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You're on the right track with `AccuracyGoal`, which by default is about `10^-8`. Not coincidentally, as `y[r]` approaches `10^-8`, noise starts to creep in.  You should think of `AccuracyGoal` as setting a tolerance such that within that tolerance, numbers should be treated as roughly equivalent to zero.  But because of rounding error, it should not be so great (such as `Infinity`) that it is impossible to achieve at the chose working precision.  So `AccuracyGoal` needs to be great enough that the accuracy throughout the interval of integration is great enough to get enough digits of precision for a satisfactory result. At machine precision, setting it to ~16 digits more than `-Log10` of the "average" value of `y[r]` over a "substantial" interval (e.g., ignore zero crossings).  So

```
AccuracyGoal -> 24
```

seems a reasonable choice.  Over a lengthy interval like this, error can still accumulate, and some slight fuzziness can be seen at the end.  I've had success sometimes increasing the `PrecisionGoal` to a little more than half working precision, (Half working precision is the standard default and is a somewhat conservative heuristic.)  For machine precision (~15.95), `PrecisionGoal -> 10` is often achievable, but usually not one higher than `12`.

So with that in mind, this seems to get the expected and sought-after result:

```
FAu1[q_] := If[q == 0,
   1,
   NDSolveValue[
    {y'[r] == 1/92.57237188637842 Sin[q r]/q r/(1 + E^((r - 6.38)/0.535)), 
      y[0] == 0}, y[100], {r, 0, 100}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 24, PrecisionGoal -> 10]];

Show[A, B]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]